# Wordpress: Style first post differently from the rest

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I've been searching around and cannot find the right solution. My goal is to style the first post differently from the rest. I have them in a grid 3*3, and I want to first post to be fullwidth.

The following piece of code is generating the loop in the index.php.

```
<ul class="list_post">

            <?php $i = 1; ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                    

                <?php get_template_part('content','grid'); ?>                                          
                <?php if ($i%3 == 0) : ?>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <?php endif; $i++; ?>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?> 

</ul>
```

The rendered HTML-output is:

```html
<ul class="list_post">
  <li>
    <article id="post-7375" class="post_grid post-7375 post type-post status-publish format-video has-post-thumbnail hentry post_format-post-format-video">
      <div class="post-img"></div>
      <div class="post-header"></div>
      <div class="post-entry"></div>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>(..)</li>
  <li>(..)</li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure how this can be done?

Comment: Use CSS. `ul.list_post li:first-child{...}`

Comment: Good suggestion, but that don't work. It doesn't trigger the first:post.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "It doesn't trigger the first:post". What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: But your code seems like you trying to put clearfix after every 3 posts. your question is not clear and why you don't try `if ($i == 1) { //This is first post }` and after first post $i will be greater than 1

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, updated the first post here with html-output and more information.

Comment: Perhaps `ul.list_post li:first-child article{...}`?

Comment: try `.list_post:first-child li { } `

Comment: @ISuthanBala you made it, but it doesn't look like the best solution, because the row below is cutted to only 2 posts (instead of 3) when I set article {full:width:100%}. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Change the if statement to `<?php if (($i + 1) %3 == 0) : ?>` because the index will be always one greater than the 'small' posts.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ISuthanBala, but that destroy the grid (3x3).

Comment: @Musa Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ of the results?

Comment: Actually, start with `$i = 0;` instead of `$i=1`

Comment: @ISuthanBala this is the best jsfiddle I could make: https://jsfiddle.net/gcbxyste/ I dont know why the grid is 2x2, but on my site 3x3 tho. Thanks.

Comment: @Musa hmm did the changing the value of `$i` fixed it? if not, can you insert some more posts and just update the HTML part of the jsfiddle?

Comment: @ISuthanBala no, it didnt fix. when using the method you gave, this is the output of the layout now: http://imgur.com/6VxQmTa. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it either, because I need to style the title size, and maybe add some more functions in that first post like category, date etc. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

On the `content-grid.php` change your first few lines to reflect the following:

```
global $i;

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('article-num-' . $i); ?>>
```

Then in your CSS, you can do:

```
.article-num-1{
..
}
```